# Change GET's values

Tags: php, get

I want to change my GET's values in PHP.

**For example, I want to change this:**

```
mypage.com/?lang=fr&page=home&...
```

**To this:**

```
mypage.com/?lang=en&page=home&...
```

I could make it with an `str_replace` and `substr` but I'm looking a less stupid way.

I would like to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you would like to redirect to a different page?

Comment: Are you creating these links in PHP to place on a page, or are you looking to change the value of $_GET['lang'] in the script the link calls? Either way, what does 'less stupid' mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the value in the `$_GET` superglobal, then recreate the URL:

```
$root_url = "example.com";

// redefine $_GET['lang']
$_GET['lang'] = "en";

// build the new URL    
$new_url = $root_url . "?" . http_build_query($_GET);

// redirect
header("Location: {$new_url}");
```

Here is a [codepad](http://codepad.org/PWSWgAgI)

Comment: Beaten to the punch. +1

Comment: Nice but I lost my other get's no ?

Comment: @FrancoisM: No, the `$_GET` superglobal retains the other keys it has. You're not removing them, nor are you redeclaring the superglobal. You are only redeclaring the value of `$_GET['lang']`

Comment: Rather than overwriting the global input array, a in-place [union](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) like `array("lang"=>"en")+$_GET` might be advisable.

Comment: @mario: How would that behave if `$_GET` already has a key `lang`? Also, any advantage of your proposal over directly modifying `$_GET`?

Comment: The first one takes precedence, it just appends the remaining `$_GET` keys and values. Modifying the input can also be an option, but I'd be wary of implications on other code parts when modifying the superglobals.

Comment: I'd simply copy the `$_GET` array to another variable first and do the manipulation. [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76406/directly-modifying-superglobals) might be an interesting read about directly modifying superglobals.

Answer (score 0):

```
$parse_url = parse_url($url);
$queryString = explode('&',$parse_url['query']);
print_r($parse_url);
foreach ($queryString as $queryStringKey => $queryStringValue) {
    $node = explode('=',$queryStringValue);
    $key = reset($node);
    $val = end($node);
    if($key == 'lang'){
        $queryString[$queryStringKey] = $key . '=' . 'fr';
    }   
}
$queryString = implode('&', $queryString);
echo $parse_url['host'] . $parse_url['path'] . '?' .   $queryString;
```